# Using Video as Mask of Video with Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, video

I have been trying to create a dynamic mask from one video onto another one. Neither videos have an alpha channel (and even then it would have low support in browsers right now), so I am trying to solve the issue with `canvas`. I have managed to get it done in very limited cycles, but it still isn't able to do this at a decent frame rate in my output (it hits about 20 fps and it should at least get 25/30 to appear smooth). It is actually running in Singular with other elements around it, so I need to get it more efficient.

Due to confidentiality I can't actually share the actual videos, but one contains the alpha mask (`mask.mp4`) in black and white (and shades of gray in between) while the other video content can be anything that needs to be masked (`video.mp4`).

The code that I want to improve is actually this (assume all videos and canvas elements are `1920x1080`):

```js
const video = document.getElementById( 'video' ); // `<video src="video.mp4"></video>
const mask = document.getElementById( 'mask' ); // `<video src="mask.mp4"></video>
const buffer = document.getElementById( 'buffer' ); // <canvas hidden></canvas>
const bufferCtx = buffer.getContext( '2d' );
const output = document.getElementById( 'output' ); // <canvas></canvas>
const outputCtx = output.getContext( '2d' );

outputCtx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in';

function maskVideo(){
    
    // Draw the mask
    bufferCtx.drawImage( mask, 0, 0 );
    
    // Get image data
    const data = bufferCtx.getImageData( 0, 0, w, h );
     
    // Assign the grayscale value to the alpha in the image data
    for( let i = 0; i < data.data.length; i += 4 ){
    
        data.data[i+3] = data.data[i];
    
    }
    
    // Put in the data
    outputCtx.putImageData( data, 0, 0 );
    // Draw the masked video into the mask (see the globalCompositeOperation above)
    outputCtx.drawImage( video, 0, 0, w, h );
    
    window.requestAnimationFrame( maskVideo );

}

window.requestAnimationFrame( maskVideo );
```

So my question is: **is there any more efficient way of masking out black pixels from another video** while both videos are running? I am currently not worried about concurrency (the difference between both streams is less than a millisecond, much less than an actual frame in the video itself). **The goal is to improve framerates.**

Here is the more expansive code snippet that unfortunately doesn't work on stack overflow for obvious CORS and video hosting reasons:

```js
const video = document.getElementById( 'video' );
const mask = document.getElementById( 'mask' );
const buffer = document.getElementById( 'buffer' );
const bufferCtx = buffer.getContext( '2d' );
const output = document.getElementById( 'output' );
const outputCtx = output.getContext( '2d' );
const fpsOutput = document.getElementById( 'fps' );
const w = 1920;
const h = 1080;

let currentError;
let FPSCount = 0;

output.width =
buffer.width = w;
output.height =
buffer.height = h;

outputCtx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in';

function maskVideo(){

    if( !video.paused ){

        bufferCtx.drawImage( mask, 0, 0 );

        const data = bufferCtx.getImageData( 0, 0, w, h );

        for( let i = 0; i < data.data.length; i += 4 ){

            data.data[i+3] = data.data[i];

        }

        outputCtx.putImageData( data, 0, 0 );
        outputCtx.drawImage( video, 0, 0, w, h );

        FPSCount++;

    } else if( FPSCount ){

        fpsOutput.textContent = (FPSCount / video.duration * video.playbackRate).toFixed(2);
        FPSCount = 0;

    }

    window.requestAnimationFrame( maskVideo );

}

window.requestAnimationFrame( maskVideo );
```

```css
html {
    font-size: 1vh;
    font-size: calc(var(--scale,1) * 1vh);
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
video {
    display: none;
}
canvas {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
#fps {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    background: red;
    color: white;
    z-index: 5;
    font-size: 50px;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Courier, monospace;
    font-variant-numeric: tabular-nums;
}
#fps:after {
    content: 'fps';
}
```

```html
<video id="video" src="./video.mp4" preload muted hidden></video>
<video id="mask" src="./mask.mp4" preload muted hidden></video>
<canvas id="output"></canvas>
<canvas id="buffer" hidden></canvas>

<p id="fps" hidden></p>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One trick is to do your chroma key on a smaller version of the video.
Generally on videos you won't really notice that the masking has lesser quality than the actual visible video. However the CPU will notice it has a lot less pixels to compare.
You can even smooth a bit the edges by applying a small blur filter over the mask:

```js
(async() => {
const video = document.getElementById( 'video' );
const mask = document.getElementById( 'mask' );
const buffer = document.getElementById( 'buffer' );
// since we're going to do a lot of readbacks on the context
// we should let the browser know,
// so that it doesn't move it from and to the GPU every time
// For this we use the { willReadFrequently: true } option
const bufferCtx = buffer.getContext( '2d', { willReadFrequently: true } );
const output = document.getElementById( 'output' );
const outputCtx = output.getContext( '2d' );


await video.play();
await mask.play();

const w = video.videoWidth;
const h = video.videoHeight;
output.width  = w;
output.height = h;
buffer.width  = mask.videoWidth  / 5; // do the chroma on a smaller version
buffer.heigth = mask.videoHeight / 5;

function maskVideo(){

    if( !video.paused ){

        bufferCtx.drawImage( mask, 0, 0, buffer.width, buffer.height );

        const data = bufferCtx.getImageData( 0, 0, buffer.width, buffer.height );

        for( let i = 0; i < data.data.length; i += 4 ) {
            data.data[i+3] = data.data[i];
        }
        // we put the new ImageData back on buffer
        // so that we can stretch it on the output context
        // alternatively we could have created an ImageBitmap from the ImageData
        bufferCtx.putImageData( data, 0, 0 );
        outputCtx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
        outputCtx.filter = "blur(1px)"; // smoothen the mask
        outputCtx.drawImage( buffer, 0, 0, w, h );
        outputCtx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in';
        outputCtx.filter = "none";
        outputCtx.drawImage( video, 0, 0, w, h );
        outputCtx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';

    }

    window.requestAnimationFrame( maskVideo );

}

window.requestAnimationFrame( maskVideo );
})();
```

```html
<video id="video" src="https://dl8.webmfiles.org/big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm" preload muted hidden loop></video>
<!-- not a great mask video example since it's really in shades of grays -->
<video id="mask" preload muted loop hidden src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/64/Plan_9_from_Outer_Space_%281959%29.webm" crossorigin="anonymous"></video>
<canvas id="output"></canvas>
<canvas id="buffer" hidden></canvas>
```

An other solution since your mask is white&black is to use an SVG filter, notabily an `<feColorMatrix type=luminanceToAlpha>`. This should leave all the work on the GPU side, and remove the need for an intermediary buffer canvas, however note that Safari browsers still don't support that option...

```js
(async() => {
const video = document.getElementById( 'video' );
const mask = document.getElementById( 'mask' );
const output = document.getElementById( 'output' );
const outputCtx = output.getContext( '2d' );


await video.play();
await mask.play();

const w = output.width  = video.videoWidth;
const h = output.height = video.videoHeight;

function maskVideo(){

    outputCtx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
    outputCtx.filter = "url(#lumToAlpha)";
    outputCtx.drawImage( mask, 0, 0, w, h );
    outputCtx.filter = "none";
    outputCtx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in';
    outputCtx.drawImage( video, 0, 0, w, h );
    outputCtx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';

    window.requestAnimationFrame( maskVideo );

}

window.requestAnimationFrame( maskVideo );
})();
```

```html
<video id="video" src="https://dl8.webmfiles.org/big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm" preload muted hidden loop></video>
<video id="mask" preload muted loop hidden src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/64/Plan_9_from_Outer_Space_%281959%29.webm" crossorigin="anonymous"></video>
<canvas id="output"></canvas>
<svg width=0 height=0 style=visibility:hidden;position:absolute>
  <filter id=lumToAlpha>
    <feColorMatrix type="luminanceToAlpha" />
  </filter>
</svg>
```

Comment: Both of these solutions are great - I'm in favour of the second one (I had found something about this on Stack overflow but it involved a huge amount of 0 values zeroing out etc... But I did not know about 1luminanceToAlpha1!) Both of them hit 120fps right now (the max it will do), so I'm pretty confident they can be rendered at a decent framerate in other places. It only really needs to work on chrome, but I have first solution as a backup! Cheers!